# jQueryUI dialog position broken in Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cross-browser

This seems really strange. Take a look at this fiddle in Firefox.
http://jsfiddle.net/mjT5R/1/

Note that the fiddle is the jQueryUI basic dialog demo, verbatim.

The dialog, with no styling, appears in the center of the results frame. Now try in Chrome (my version is 8.0). It's at the top left, isn't it?

Now try adding some CSS (in Chrome). Add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">` to the top of the HTML section. When styled, the position magically works!

So what gives, why is Chrome (and Safari, according to our test team) not correctly positioning the dialog? It's not just the iframe - full screen result has the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the following CSS:

```
.ui-dialog { margin:0 auto; }
```

...and it should center as you want it to.  I [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjT5R/2/) to show this.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me out. Anyone using this solution should note that if you put that in your jquery-ui theme css, you can no longer position the dialogs 'left' or 'right', so it's probably best to only put the css in a location that will only be specific to one page, unless you want all dialogs in  your application centered.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found that our css is outdated on our website. The css that makes it work is to have .ui-dialog have position: absolute. In the old version it's relative, which breaks it in Webkit.